# Generating a histogram array for detecting curve segments using Hough Transform

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, hough-transform

I basically understand the theory behind using the Hough Transform to detect parabolas (i.e. y = a( x - x_c ) + y_c).

However, I want to implement it myself in MatLab so I can see it working (I don't want to use pre-written code to do it for me).  Would someone be able to help me by giving me some pseudocode?  I.e. it doesn't have to be MatLab syntax etc.  I will be using an edge detector like for Canny edge detector to provide input to the HT.

Any help would be awesome :).  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**:
The link below is broken: the original example was from a lecture that is now [on You Tube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-n7NoLArcs&t=317s)

---

<strike>There's a detailed example (with pictures) [here](http://engineering.mines.edu/course/eggn512/lectures/17-HoughAdditionalNotes.pdf):</strike>  pseudocode is on pg5 (see below), MatLab code on pg6-7.

[image]

(There's also another MatLab example [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15841-parabola-detection-using-hough-transform?controller=file_infos&download=true)).